# Is it correct natural to use the phrasal verb "push forward" in the sense of stimulating someone or making them leave their comfort zone?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, phrase-choice

Is it correct natural  to use the phrasal verb *push forward* in the sense of stimulating someone or making someone leave their comfort zone? For example:

> I am quite shy, but my friend is always **pushing** me **forward**.
>
> The CEO **pushes** us **forward** to work harder.

If it's not natural or correct, what would you say instead?

Comment: Take a look at this "https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/push+forward". It seems that "stimulating someone" is more close to the meaning of "push forward".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, 'push forward' is not used like that.

From my experience, 'push' in the context of people is often negative, and you are not 'pushed *forward*' but just 'pushed'. It implies that the action is forceful - see the meaning 'to forcefully persuade' in [this dictionary entry](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/push).

> The CEO pushes us to work harder.
>
> My football coach pushes me to do better.

If your CEO is a great leader, he or she might 'inspire' you to work harder. 
If your boss is a good manager, he or she might 'encourage' you to work harder.
I can't think of a word that means exactly what you want to say, but you could look at the definitions or synonyms of 'to inspire', 'to encourage' or the less formal 'to spur on'.